# Can't connect my Ajax html with my Java servlet

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

I've been working on this for hours, searching online for people with similar issues and potential solutions, and I keep on getting stuck.  I am trying to write an Ajax enabled html form implemented in javascript which will access some data from a servlet with file extension .java and save it somewhere on the html page.  I'm new to writing servlets and to writing Ajax- I have limited html and javascript experience, so I'm sure I'm missing something simple and obvious, but as I said, I've been working at this for hours, and I simply cannot see it.  Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.  (Code below:)

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Display Votes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        var xmlhttp;

        function getVotes() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var url = "DisplayMyVotesServlet?loginID=APP&password=pass";
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
            xmlhttp.send();
        }           
        function callback() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                alert(xmlhttp.readyState == 4);
                var theResult = xmlhttp.responseText.documentElement;
                alert(theResult);
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = theResult;              
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" value="My Votes" onclick="getVotes()"/>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

and my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "DisplayMyVotesServlet", urlPatterns = {"/DisplayMyVotesServlet"})
public class DisplayMyVotesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource (name = "jdbc/HW2DB")
    private DataSource datasource;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
        String selectSQL = "select * from VOTES";
        PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        ResultSet resultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery();
        int numTotalVotes = 0;
        while(resultSet.next())
            numTotalVotes = numTotalVotes + resultSet.getInt("NUMVOTES");
        String result = "I have voted " + numTotalVotes + " times.";
        request.setAttribute("Result", result);
        resultSet.close();
        selectStatement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```